# How to convert `Configuration.GetSection` from .NET Core 5 to .NET Core 6?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-6.0

I am trying to convert from .NET Core 5 to .NET Core 6.

In my .NET Core 5, `Startup.cs`, I have

```
public class Startup
{
        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            // ...
            Configuration.GetSection("sectionName")
        }
}
```

In .NET Core 6, `Startup.cs` is removed. And from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/50-to-60?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio , I don't see how can I read `Configuration` section from configuration file, `appsettings.json`.

Can you please point me where I can find example to do that in .NET 6?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In .Net 6 , `Configuration` has been configured in Program.cs, You just need to use:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
//.......
builder.Services.Configure<Your model>(configuration.GetSection("sectionName"));
```

to Map appSettings.json object to class.

Or you can just use:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
//.......
builder.Configuration.GetSection("sectionName")
```

to read the value in `appsetting.json`.